# De Bruijn sequence generation in Java

Tags: java

i've been working on code that should generate a De Bruijn sequence/array for my project about De Bruijn sequences and i've run across this particular code:

```
import java.util.*;
 
class GFG
{
 
    static Set<String> seen = new HashSet<String>();
    static Vector<Integer> edges = new Vector<Integer>();
 
    // Modified DFS in which no edge
    // is traversed twice
    static void dfs(String node, int k, String A)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i)
        {
            String str = node + A.charAt(i);
            if (!seen.contains(str))
            {
                seen.add(str);
                dfs(str.substring(1), k, A);
                edges.add(i);
            }
        }
    }
 
    // Function to find a de Bruijn sequence
    // of order n on k characters
    static String deBruijn(int n, int k, String A)
    {
 
        // Clearing global variables
        seen.clear();
        edges.clear();
 
        String startingNode = string(n - 1, A.charAt(0));
        dfs(startingNode, k, A);
 
        String S = "";
 
        // Number of edges
        int l = (int) Math.pow(k, n);
        for (int i = 0; i < l; ++i)
            S += A.charAt(edges.get(i));
        S += startingNode;
 
        return S;
    }
 
    private static String string(int n, char charAt)
    {
        String str = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            str += charAt;
        return str;
    }
 
    // Driver code
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int n = 3, k = 2;
        String A = "01";
 
        System.out.print(deBruijn(n, k, A));
    }
}
 
// This code is contributed by 29AjayKumar
```

The question in hand is how does this actually generate the correct sequence? I'm asking because when professor taught us he mentioned going via hamiltonian path/eulerian cycle so i'm bugged why this code works since it doesn't seem to implement any of said two.

A bit confused but i would appreciate someone smarter breaking me down how and why.

I tried running code based off of the textbook examples done in my notebook by hand, it matches the sequences but not in a way that i understand.